# How to pass an array of struct to pthread_create? C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, arguments, pthreads

Help!!!! 
How can I cast **args.tab1** to **(void *)** and pass it as an **argument** of **pthread**? Thanks

//struct

```
typedef struct args args; 
struct args {
    int *tab1;
    int *tab2;
    int *tab3;
    int *tab4;
};
```

//pthread

```
args args; //define struct
pthread_t tid;
pthread_create(&tid, NULL, function1, (void *)args.tab1);
pthread_join(tid, NULL);
```

//function1

```
void *function1(void *input)
{
    int *arr = (int*)input;
    function2(arr);
}

//function2
void function2(int *arr) 
{
...
}
```

Comment: Do you want to pass the struct or just tab1?

Comment: Hello Tony, just tab1 but iam curious to know how to pass the entire struc too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to cast. The compiler will not complain when casting any pointer to `void *`. Just do

```c
    args a;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, function1, a.tab1);
```

Comment: Thanks Marcelo for your reply! I just edit my question. I forgot to add the typedef in the question. How can I pass only tab1?

Comment: Ok, I have fixed the response accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Marcelo, it works! :) can you explain me why we need to add the &?

Comment: You only need it if you are passing a pointer to arg.tab1, i.e., if you want to alter the value of the pointer itself. If all you want to have access or alter the integer value arg.tab1 points to, then you don't want to use `&`. Notice that I have changed this in my answer when you changed your code.

Answer (score 0):

A demo on how to pass a struct

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct args {
    int *tab1;
    int *tab2;
    int *tab3;
    int *tab4;
};

void *f(void *arg)
{
    struct args *o = (struct args *)arg;
    printf("%d\n", *(o->tab1));
    printf("%d\n", *(o->tab2));
    printf("%d\n", *(o->tab3));
    printf("%d\n", *(o->tab4));
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread1;
    int n = 100;
    struct args o = {
        .tab1 = &n,
        .tab2 = &n,
        .tab3 = &n,
        .tab4 = &n
    };

    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, f, &o);
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
}
```

Alternatively, you could

```
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, f, o);
```

If `o` wasn't on stack (i.e. you allocated memory for it and it's the pointer to that memory).

Output:

```
100
100
100
100
```

---

And if you only wish to pass a single pointer from `struct args` then

```
void *f(void *arg)
{
        int* tab1 = (int *)arg;
        printf("%d\n", *tab1);
}

int main()
{
   ...
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, f, o.tab1);
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tony for the reply, i uderstand better how to passe the struct. Is there any way to pass only tab1?